# "Beautifying" an OS X disk image

Tags: macos, icons, skype, diskimage

When I downloaded Skype, I noticed that, in place of a normal "disk image" icon, there was a custom icon, and when I double clicked on the icon, the window used a colorful image as the background, prompting me to drag the skype icon into the applications folder.

How can I do that with my applications?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 14):

Let me add to the other answers [jwz's howto](http://www.jwz.org/blog/2006/03/setting-view-options-on-dmg-files/) on setting view options on .dmg files. This is the simplest one that I got to work with no problems.

Also, to change the icon from the default .dmg icon:

- In the Finder, open an inspector window (^I) for the file whose icon you want to use, click on the icon at the top (it will get a blue border) and copy it to the clipboard (^C).
- Then open another inspector for your .dmg, click on the icon and press ^V to paste

(you can change the icon for any file like this).

For this kind of thing, you can always look at open-source programs and see what they do to get a similar result. For example here are the relevant source files for building pretty dmg files in:

- [Adium](http://trac.adiumx.com/browser/trunk/Release)
- [Miro](https://develop.participatoryculture.org/trac/democracy/browser/trunk/tv/platform/osx)

Answer (score 4):

If you’re interested in a commercial solution, there are a number of DMG designer apps available, including the following I gleaned from a [MacUpdate search](http://www.macupdate.com/search.php?starget=google&keywords=dmg):

- [DMG Packager](http://freespace.virgin.net/jeremy.dronfield/skoobysoft/utilities/dmgp.html)
- [DMG Architect](http://sourcebits.com/dmg/)
- [DMG Canvas](http://www.araelium.com/dmgcanvas/)

Comment: Looking back now I can’t believe I missed DropDMG…

Answer (score 2):

This is a great freeware solution for a custom background with zero hassle:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dmgcreator/